# how can i remove class active from a button after getting clicked again while it's active with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two buttons that they're going to show some content after getting clicked each one. the buttons are inactive at first. after getting hovered and clicked, they'll get the active class.
the problem is by clicking on the active button again, it's going to collapse the div element which is ok but that active button doesn't get inactive after getting clicked for the second time.

and keep in mind that my collapse part is not working properly in snippet which I don't know why ( actually it's working perfectly in my project) and it's not a very important issue cos it doesn't affect the main issue I discussed above.
so the question is: how can I inactivate the active button after getting clicked for the second time cos it's gonna collapse its div element so basically when the specified div element is collapsed, its button shouldn't be active anymore.
does anybody know where my mistake is?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Resume-items li', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'),
        document.getElementsByClassName('.Resume-click-open').style.height = '100px'
});

jQuery('.btn-Resume-buttons').click(function (e) {
    jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
#Resume-items {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#Resume-items li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 25px;

}

#Resume-items .btn {
    color: black;
    background: rgba(168, 198, 222, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.9rem 1.8rem;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.btn.btn-Resume-buttons::before {
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: left;
}

.btn.btn-Resume-buttons {
    transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.btn.btn-Resume-buttons:hover::before,
.btn.btn-Resume-buttons:focus::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px black;
}

.btn.btn-Resume-buttons:hover,
.btn.btn-Resume-buttons:focus {
    color: #dae7f1 !important;
}

#Resume-items li.active .btn.btn-Resume-buttons {
    background: black;
    color: #dae7f1;
}

.Resume-click-open {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 panel-group fade-in-resume" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel justify-content-center">
        <ul id="Resume-items">
            <li class="panel-title">
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                    class="btn btn-Resume-buttons" href="#test1">test 1
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="panel-title">
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="btn btn-Resume-buttons"
                                    href="#Test2">Test 2
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
            
    <div class="Resume-click-open row">
        <div id="test1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            something1
        </div>

        <div id="test2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            something2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you are giving `backgound-color: black;` to **.btn.btn-Resume-buttons::before {**

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa no, unfortunately cos if i remove that background-color then my style gets screwed up when hovering the buttons and totally it's not going to work properly again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try thisL

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){
        $(".btn").not(this).removeClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('.Resume-click-open').css({'height' : '100px'});
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });

    $('.btn-Resume-buttons').click(function(e){
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 panel-group fade-in-resume" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel justify-content-center">
        <ul id="Resume-items">
            <li class="panel-title">
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="btn btn-Resume-buttons" href="#test1">test 1</button>
            </li>
            <li class="panel-title">
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="btn btn-Resume-buttons" href="#Test2">Test 2</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
            
    <div class="Resume-click-open row">
        <div id="test1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            something1
        </div>

        <div id="test2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            something2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Resume-items {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#Resume-items li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 25px;

}

#Resume-items .btn {
    color: black;
    background: rgba(168, 198, 222, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.9rem 1.8rem;
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index:1;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: #dae7f1 !important;
}

.btn.btn-Resume-buttons::before {
    content: '';
    width:0;
    min-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:-1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #000;
}

.btn.btn-Resume-buttons:hover::before {
    color: #dae7f1 !important;
    width:100%;
}

.btn.active {
    background: #00b32d !important;
    color: #dae7f1 !important;
}

.Resume-click-open {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks but there is one big problem which is not what i want. after clicking on any button, it's gonna get active with a background-color of green but after clicking on another button, the previous shouldn't be active anymore ( with no background color) and you need to click on every active button again in order to remove that green background. just one button must be active at a time.

Comment: thats's easy just need to add one line, check it on the jquery

Comment: yeah i checked the codes on js fiddle. as i explained, there must be no background color after the button(s) getting clicked twice ( when they are not active anymore). i mean when the site is refreshed, no button is active at first. then when we click on one of them, they get active by a black background color ( not any other color) and when we click on that active button again, we shouldn't see any active button anymore and it's gonna collapse its div element part. pat attention that when i say they shouldn't be active it means that the background color must be rgba(168, 198, 222, 0.4).

Comment: which the codes here are not doing this. i will really appreciate if you can tell me how to change the styles or my jquery in order to get such a result cos i'm not really professional in Jquery and this part.

Comment: also i added that new jquery part which you've edited and it's not still working the way i want. if you can check it out on js fiddle, you will find out where i'm actually implying.

Comment: sorry I just got what you want. check it now.

Comment: oh dear Mohsen, thank you very much. after so many days struggling with this strange part, it is finally working properly. i had to change some of your codes in order to get the exact result i was looking for for my own website ( especially the CSS part). of course without your help and patience, it wasn't possible. thanks a million! you are perfect :)

Comment: @Matin you're welcome, I'm glad that i could help